# Outlook 2016 Run a script option missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, autorun

i tried to add my script to auto download attachments which were coming to me to a specific folder which will be further processed by Excel Macro. but i don't any option to add script in rules. May be client side scripting is not allowed in network. any suggestions please?

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Add the `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules` value of `1` (DWORD) to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security` registry key to enable "run a script" action. After that, restart Outlook.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir. this worked for me. I'm very Happy today. It will help me get a one step progress in my automation work.

Comment: @SumitPatil, glad to hear! Please mark this as answer if it helped you.